# Animate overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this piece, which I want to animate the div going down and up while still showing part of the content. See working at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xx8Lkhtf/).

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.wrap').animate().css({
        'overflow-y' : 'visible',
        'max-height' : 'initial'
    });
});
```

Comment: you should explain better what you want to do.

Comment: Agree with Claudiu as it's difficult to understand what effect you are trying to accomplish with your code.

Comment: How much more simpler can I explain it. Don't you see the working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation statement appears to be incorrect. The code below should get you started.  Also see the examples in the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
 $('button').click(function(){
        $('.wrap').animate({ maxHeight: '400px' }, 3000 );
    });
```

Yet, if you want to slide up and down on the button click then the jQuery toggle method might work better for you. See [jQuery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)